# Trigger alert if date and time is same selected in time picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, datetimepicker

I need to show an alert when the user selects a date which is the current date. When selecting a time they should get an alert if the time is not further than 3 hours from current time.

```js
$('#datetimepicker4').timepicker({
  timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
  change: function() {
    var startTime = $("#datetimepicker4").val().substring(0, 2);
    var endTime = $("#datetimepicker5").val().substring(0, 2);
    var stTime = parseInt(startTime) + parseInt(numberTwo);
    var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');

    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0);
    today.setMinutes(0);
    today.setSeconds(0);

    var dt = new Date();
    var phours = dt.getHours() + 3;

    if (Date.parse(today) == Date.parse(selectedDate)) {
      if (parseInt(startTime) <= parseInt(phours)) {
        alert("choose time 3 hours after current time");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not just set the `minTime` on the timepicker? You've not stated exactly which library you're using, but most of them have that ability.

Comment: i am using jquery timepicker but, minTime is not working for me i dont know why,

Comment: Which specific one? Can you link to it

Comment: https://timepicker.co/

Comment: Then definitely use `minTime`. It's demo usage is in the example at the bottom of the page you linked to

Comment: minTime is working when i define it already but not dynamically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207094/discussion-between-kamran-hassan-and-rory-mccrossan).